# Condition expectation exponential variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions

Let $A=\{\Omega, \emptyset, [0,c],(c,\infty)\}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra.
I want to compute $E[X\mid A](\omega)$ for $\omega \in [0,c]$ and $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$. Let's define $\mu(dx)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx$ What I've is the following:
$$E[X\mid A]=\frac{1}{\mu(0,c)}\int_0^c x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx = \frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda c}} \left[-c e^{-\lambda c}-\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda c}+\frac{1}{\lambda} \right]=\frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{c}{e^{\lambda c}-1}.$$

For $\omega \in (c,\infty)$ I know that the conditional expectation equals $c+\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$.

Now I have to show that $E[E[X\mid A]]=E[X]$ but adding these answers does not give $E[X]=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$.
Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: You don't just add the answers. You need to weight them by $P(A)$ and $P(A^c)$.

Comment: Yes @MichaelHardy. Sorry for the unclear phrasing.

Comment: First some routine stuff in a comment:
$$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X\le c) = \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}} \int_0^c x e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda\,dx) = \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}} \int_0^c x e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda\,dx)$$
$$= \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}}\cdot \frac 1 \lambda \int_0^c (\lambda x) e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda\,dx) $$
$$= \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}}\cdot \frac 1 \lambda \int_0^{\lambda c} u (e^{-u} \, du) $$
$$= \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}}\cdot \frac 1 \lambda \int u \, dv $$
$$= \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}}\cdot \frac 1 \lambda \left( uv - \int v\,du \right)$$

Comment: $$= \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}}\cdot \frac 1 \lambda \left( \left[ -ue^{-u} \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right]_0^{\lambda c} + \int_0^{\lambda c} e^{-u} \,du \right)$$
$$= \frac 1 {1- e^{-\lambda c}}\cdot \frac 1 \lambda \left( 1 - e^{-\lambda c} - \lambda c e^{-\lambda c}\right)$$
So far this agrees with you, EXCEPT that you computed the constant $\operatorname{E}(X\mid X\le c)$ rather than the random variable $\operatorname{E}(X\mid A)$. $\qquad\qquad$

Comment: The question now seems clear.  Notice the MathJax code for $A=\{\Omega, \emptyset, [0,c],(c,\infty)\}$ (I edited that part a bit). $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$E[E[X\mid A]] = \int_\Omega E[X\mid A](\omega) \, dP(\omega)
=\int_{\{X\in[0,c]\}}E[X\mid A](\omega) \, dP(\omega) + \int_{\{X\in(c,\infty)\}} E[X\mid A](\omega) \, dP(\omega).
$$
On the two sets $\{X\in[0,c]\}$ and $\{X\in(c,\infty)\}$ the value of $E[X\mid A]$ is constant, as you've calculated (correctly). Pull out the constants and you'll multiply them with the probabilities of the two sets. This should get you the right answer $1/\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find four numbers:

- $a=\operatorname{E}(X\mid X\le c)$,
- $b=\operatorname{E}(X\mid X> c)$,
- $p=\Pr(X\le c)$,
- $q=\Pr(X > c)$.

You've already found the first two and it is clear you know how to find the others.

Then the random variable $\operatorname{E}(X\mid A)$ is
$$
\operatorname{E}(X\mid A) = \left. \begin{cases} a & \text{if } X\le c, \\  b & \text{if } X > c, \end{cases} \right\} = \begin{cases} a & \text{with probability } p, \\ b & \text{with probability }q. \end{cases}
$$
In other words, conditioning the expected value on $A$ means finding conditional expected values when you are given information telling you which members of $A$ the outcome $\omega$ is in.

The expected value of that is $ap+bq$ and should be the same as the expected value of $X$.

Comment: But then I get c+$\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$?

Comment: @RoosJansen : Here's what I get:
$$
a = \operatorname{E}(X\mid X\le c) = \frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{c}{e^{\lambda c}-1}.
$$
$$
p = \Pr( X\le c ) = 1 - e^{-\lambda c}.
$$
$$
b = \operatorname{E}(X\mid X>c) = c+ \frac 1 \lambda
$$
$$
q = \Pr(X > c) = e^{-\lambda c}
$$
$$
\operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid A)) = ap+bq = \left( \frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{c}{e^{\lambda c}-1} \right) (1-e^{-\lambda c}) + \left( c + \frac 1 \lambda \right) e^{-\lambda c} 
$$
$$
= \frac 1 \lambda(1-e^{-\lambda c}) - ce^{-\lambda c} + ce^{-\lambda c} + \frac 1 \lambda e^{-\lambda c} = \frac 1 \lambda.
$$